# symfony2 create custom query inside entity - getEntityManager() undefined

Tags: symfony, undefined-behavior

I am looking to run a custom query inside my entity class.  I dont want to use table mapping for this query I just want to return an array of results but I would like the query to still log to the logger.  I have stripped down the class and renamed to try and illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

```
// src/Name/ExampleBundle/Entity/ExampleEntity.php

namespace Name\ExampleBundle\Entity;

class ExampleEntity
{

    public function getArrayFromExample(){

        $results = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("SELECT * FROM exmapleTable LIMIT 50")
        ->getResult();

        return $results;
    }

}
```

The above returns something like

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method {path}\ExampleEntity::getEntityManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your queries should be in an entity repository instead of the entity itself. http://mackstar.com/blog/2010/10/04/using-repositories-doctrine-2

Then you could do something like:

```
public function getArrayFromExample(){
    $results = $this->_em
    ->createQuery("SELECT * FROM exmapleTable LIMIT 50")
    ->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: what about for inserting data should that be in the repository also?

Comment: For insert you should edit the entity and persist it with the entity manager.